# Autoit Load File into

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to make a form to select certain samples from a file and add it to another file.. Can't figure out why it wont work.. I tried it with and without the array, and the program just lists the file location instead of contents.. Also any chance someone has something like this already setup with each list attached to a file?

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GUIListBox.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Global $aDate, $aTime
$text = ClipGet()
$sFileName = "\\SERVER\Server H\Staff Dropbox\blah\" & @MON & @MDAY & @YEAR & ".que"

#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
$Form2 = GUICreate("Choices Dialog", 345, 252, -1, -1)
$ListBox1 = GUICtrlCreateList("", 8, 8, 137, 201)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "Item1|Item2|Item3|Item4|Item5")
$Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton(">", 156, 15, 30, 25)
$Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton(">>", 156, 48, 31, 25)
$Button3 = GUICtrlCreateButton("<", 157, 81, 31, 25)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
$Button4 = GUICtrlCreateButton("<<", 157, 114, 32, 25)
$ListBox2 = GUICtrlCreateList("", 200, 8, 137, 201)
$Button5 = GUICtrlCreateButton("&OK", 104, 225, 75, 25)
$Button6 = GUICtrlCreateButton("&Cancel", 184, 225, 75, 25)
$Clear = GUICtrlCreateButton("&Clear", 264, 225, 75, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###
GUICtrlSetData($ListBox1, "")
GUICtrlSetData($ListBox2, "")

$FileNameList = FileReadToArray($sFileName)

GUICtrlSetData($ListBox1, $sFileNameList)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
         Case $Button6
            Exit
         Case $Clear
            GUICtrlSetData($ListBox1, "")


    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: Check that sFilename is computed correctly. What's its value before the call to `FileReadToArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Correct using of `_FileReadToArray` is [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileReadToArray.htm).
Thus you must use:

```
_FileReadToArray($sFileName, $aFileContent)
```

Also probably you need to update your Autoit version to latest.
Complete code:

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GUIListBox.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global $aDate, $aTime, $aFileContent
$text = ClipGet()
$sFileName = "\\SERVER\Server H\Staff Dropbox\blah\" & @MON & @MDAY & @YEAR & ".que"

#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
$Form2 = GUICreate("Choices Dialog", 345, 252, -1, -1)
$ListBox1 = GUICtrlCreateList("", 8, 8, 137, 201)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "Item1|Item2|Item3|Item4|Item5")
$Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton(">", 156, 15, 30, 25)
$Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton(">>", 156, 48, 31, 25)
$Button3 = GUICtrlCreateButton("<", 157, 81, 31, 25)
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
$Button4 = GUICtrlCreateButton("<<", 157, 114, 32, 25)
$ListBox2 = GUICtrlCreateList("", 200, 8, 137, 201)
$Button5 = GUICtrlCreateButton("&OK", 104, 225, 75, 25)
$Button6 = GUICtrlCreateButton("&Cancel", 184, 225, 75, 25)
$Clear = GUICtrlCreateButton("&Clear", 264, 225, 75, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###
GUICtrlSetData($ListBox1, "")
GUICtrlSetData($ListBox2, "")

_FileReadToArray($sFileName, $aFileContent)

if not IsArray($aFileContent) then
    msgbox(16,"Error","File read error")
    Exit
EndIf

;~ _ArrayDisplay($aFileContent)  ; to check content of  array

for $i = 1 to Ubound($aFileContent)-1
    GUICtrlSetData($ListBox1, $aFileContent[$i])
Next

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
         Case $Button6
            Exit
         Case $Clear
            GUICtrlSetData($ListBox1, "")
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```